What's a reliable metric to measure an artist's success these days?
Ever since records became a thing, record sales and charts have always been a (somewhat subjective) metric used to measure an artist's success and popularity. Artist x sold platinum in country y and so on.
Nowadays, record sales is definitely a thing of the past. So how do we accurately measure an artist's popularity? Number of views on Youtube or Spotify are very poor metrics and apparently easy to fake too - it's nowhere near as good a metric as record sales were.
One thing that comes to mind is live tour sales and total audience numbers. But I have no idea how to obtain statics of that and besides this is a poor metric too: certain genres might be far more live-friendly than others. And some artists might make great albums while being poor live, or simply appeal to an audience which isn't as likely to visit live shows. Or maybe live shows are hard to arrange in certain parts of the world because of conflicts: an artist might be popular in a certain country but unable to perform there live.
Currently there's lots of buzz about Taylor Swift just to name an example and all manner of strange statistics about her supposed record sales are displayed. Except... nobody buys records! Her biggest audience is the younger generations, which I'd say are even less likely to buy records and more likely to stream.
The term album-equivalent unit popped up when I browsed her Swift's record sales. Is it a well-established term? How reliable is this for a metric and how trustworthy is this "International Federation of the Phonographic Industry" (IFPI) behind the term? They are apparently non-profit and not in the pocket of record companies, or...?

Professional data analyst here... Bands/Artists are businesses with an incorporated name; even "Taylor Swift" is an incorporated name. There are some clever things you can do with an S-corp for tax efficiency.
The way you measure the success of an artist in a very broad way, is analyze their finances. What is going out? What is coming in? The big one: is equity growing?
Streaming pay royalties, but merchandise and your name being your property means people have to pay to use it. When a commercial plays on television and you see "TAYLOR SWIFT", they did not get to put her name there for free.
In a much narrower frame, you can benchmark bands and artists against other similar ones. You look at financial statements and compare them to other financial statements... If artist A made $100,000; artist B made $120,000; artist C made $95,000; and artist D made $500,000; we can see right away that artist D is outperforming everyone else regardless of how anyone feels about the music they sell.
You are correct that views, likes, etc. are easy to fake and they are absolutely faked.
We will never know the truth about the success level of these "megastars" for a few reasons, one of them is a big one:
1.) It's none of our business how much money people make. It does not affect our lives or contribute to society in any way, and there is no excuse for spending time worrying about how much others make for themselves.
2.) The vast majority of all popular musicians are mediocre at best, but people love them for other reasons and that skews the perception on an extreme level.
3.) This is the big one: Bands and artists and privately-owned. They do not have to report their financial health to anyone for any reason other than paying their taxes. We have no right to know; therefore, we likely never will.
One thing is for certain: you can't fake stadiums filled with people. If they are selling out shows, they're doing very well. It's hard to get 5 people in your immediate family to watch a movie together... If they have several thousand people showing up for a two-hour show, battling traffic to and from, traveling across the country to be there, getting there hours early and leaving hours late hoping to meet the performers... They're not faking their success.

Thanks for the answer, it is pretty good but I'm still hoping someone got input on this "album equivalent unit". As for not having to report sales, record companies have been happy to this since the 1950s somewhere as a way to promote artists. But with the advent of the Internet, record sales started to become a questionable metric and with streaming it now turned completely irrelevant.

I'm going to start off with these these are the forms of bias gender bias, racial bias, age bias, confirmation; bias, Halo effect, Horn effect, similarity bias, authority bias, beauty bias, and performance attrition bias. One can say that art is either subjective or perceptive giving that the artist can subject its opinion upon the listener or how the listener perceives the artist. Just think there's a metric for success is somewhat a misnomer. There's lots of people that have a lot of money, there's a lot of people that don't have any. Sales can be contributed to one of the biases or it could just be a cultural change. To be on the cusp of something it is going to change culturally which there's generally a 10 year period of a change in art in the esoteric sense to where no one has done that change 10 years later you'll see the change populated self and modern music. Some people think it's cyclical for periods and times and rehashings of old ideas. I personally prefer to think of it is a pendulum that would swing forward and swing back through the different forms of music and game momentum swinging forward and barely push the idea for for all music. But keep in mind there's all this great music in this world and you will find musicians and not entertainers pushing the ideological forms beyond what the average person we're going to do or find palatable. But if you really wish to change something new music and merit yourself as a success then be satisfied with something you do that is the only way to be satisfied. Because you can sell 10 million albums and that's great and you will be happy in a way, but if you can do one the way you want it even if no one ever hears it what would satisfy you more? And that's how you gauge your success. Don't get me wrong you know, you may never be a truly happy with your album but if you sell that many copies and you get a platinum you can at least feel dissatisfied and you're comfortable home.
